# Nested Squares in Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am a beginner in python and in school, we have an assignment to create a program using for loops to create 5 nested squares (A square inside of the center of a square 5 times). I have almost got it but I need a nudge in the right direction.

```
import turtle

scrn = turtle.Screen()
scrn.screensize(500, 500)
scrn.bgcolor('green')
mike = turtle.Turtle()
mike.shape('turtle')
mike.color('pink')
mike.penup()
mike.goto(0, -20)
mike.pendown()
length = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]

# Initialize the variable `x` before it is used.
x = 0

for i in range(5):
    # Move the turtle forward 20 pixels.
    mike.penup()
    mike.forward(20)
    mike.pendown()

    # Draw a square with side length 20+x pixels.
    for j in range(4):
        mike.forward(20+x)
        mike.left(90)

    # Update the value of `x`.
    x += length[j]

turtle.Screen().exitonclick()
```

I have tried to change the length a bit by writing every number twice but that made it worse by making the lines longer (can't really add context because it happened in an older revision). I also tried to the turtle.goto command with no luck

Comment: "but that made it worse" -- please provide details.

Comment: Note that to do nested squares, you have to move the turtle in both axes.  Something like `penup`, `forward(20)`, `right(90)`, `forward(20)`, `left(90)`, `pendown`.  Or, trickier, `right(45)`, `forward(28)`, `left(45)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: This is **not a discussion forum**, so we [do not offer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) "nudges in the right direction".

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to boil down to "draw a square centered around the point X, Y". (You can even omit X, Y and assume the center of the screen or current turtle location is the square's center). Ignore the loop for starters, and try to avoid lists. They're usually not necessary for basic turtle graphics tasks once you've figured out the pattern.

One way to draw a square around a center point heading 0 is to move forward from the center by `size / 2`, then down `size / 2`, all with the pen up. This positions the turtle at a corner of the square. You can then draw a normal square using your existing technique. Finally, lift the pen and reset the turtle back to the original heading and position it so it's ready to draw the next shape.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def draw_square(t, size):
    t.penup()

    # walk to the square's edge with the pen up
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.right(90)

    # walk to the square's corner along the edge
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.right(90)

    t.pendown()

    # draw a normal square
    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)

    # reposition the turtle back to where it started
    t.penup()
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size / 2)
    t.right(90)


t = Turtle()

for i in range(1, 6):
    draw_square(t, 50 * i)

Screen().exitonclick()
```

You can achieve the same thing with `goto`:

```py
def draw_square(t, size):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(size / 2, size / 2)
    t.setheading(-90)
    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)

    t.penup()
    t.goto(0, 0)
```

The problem with `goto` is that it's absolute, which messes up the turtle's relative position state. For bonus points, generalize to allow it to work from any turtle position like the non-`goto` version:

```py
def draw_square(t, size):
    heading = t.heading()
    x, y = t.pos()
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x + size / 2, y + size / 2)
    t.setheading(-90)
    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(90)

    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.setheading(heading)
```